# How to use typedef in ctypes

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes

I am trying to wrap a C library in Python using ctypes library.

I wrap structs this way

#### file.c

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;
```

#### file.py

```
import ctypes


class Point(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x": ctypes.c_int), ("y", ctypes.c_int)]
```

But I have a statement like this and cannot find out how to wrap it and get the type `MyFucntion`.

`typedef char* (*MyFunction)(char*);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

That's a function pointer. You can wrap it like this:

```py
FuncPtr = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))
```

But it very much depends on how are you going to make use of it.

As a side note, *typedef* doesn't have anything to do with *ctypes*: for example *Point* definition would be the same without *typedef* (`struct Point { ... };`).