# Replace a function pointer in a shared library with ctypes

Tags: python, c, callback, function-pointers, ctypes

I am trying to replace an existing function pointer in a shared library with a callback defined in Python, through ctypes.

The source of the shared library in C:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void (*plot)();

int c_main(int argc, void** argv) {
  printf("plot is %p\n", (void*)plot);
  assert(plot != NULL);
  plot();
  return 0;
}
```

The source of the Python script:

```
from sys import platform
from pathlib import Path
import ctypes
import _ctypes


FUNCTYPE = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE if platform == 'win32' else ctypes.CFUNCTYPE


def dlclose(obj):
    if platform == "win32":
        _ctypes.FreeLibrary(obj._handle)
    else:
        _ctypes.dlclose(obj._handle)


def enc_args(args):
    C_ARGS = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char) * len(args))()
    for idx, arg in enumerate(args):
        C_ARGS[idx] = ctypes.create_string_buffer(arg.encode("utf-8"))
    return C_ARGS


@FUNCTYPE(None)
def plotxy():
    print("plotxy")


C_ARGS = enc_args([str(Path(__file__))])
CAUXDLL = ctypes.CDLL("./test.so")

print(plotxy)

print(CAUXDLL.plot)

CAUXDLL.plot = plotxy

print(CAUXDLL.plot)

print(CAUXDLL.c_main(len(C_ARGS), C_ARGS))
```

The script to test it:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o test.so test.c
python3 test.py
```

The output I get:

```
# ./test.sh
<CFunctionType object at 0x7fb1f0abb1c0>
<_FuncPtr object at 0x7fb1f0abb640>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7fb1f0abb1c0>
plot is (nil)
python3: test.c:8: c_main: Assertion `plot != NULL' failed.
./test.sh: line 3: 21171 Aborted                 python3 test.py
```

So, it seems that the function defined in Python (plotxy) is of type `CFunctionType`, while the function pointer defined in C is of type `_FuncPtr`. Although the replacement in `CAUXDLL` is applied, it seems to have no effect when the main function is called.

Apart from reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes, I found other questions (e.g. [How to use typedef in ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56706290/how-to-use-typedef-in-ctypes) or [python cytpes creating callback function - Segmentation fault (core dumped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702848/python-cytpes-creating-callback-function-segmentation-fault-core-dumped)), but I cannot find how to convert `CFunctionType` (plotxy) to `_FuncPtr`.

**EDIT**

I believe this might not be an issue with the regular usage of ctypes. That's something I have successfully achieved and which is sufficiently explained in the docs. This question goes beyond. I don't want to execute the C function. I want Python to replace an existing function pointer with a callback written in Python. Note that it is possible to do it by using a helper C function (see https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl-cosim/blob/master/vhpidirect/shared/pycb/caux.c#L32-L40). Hence this question is about how to achieve it without that helper function (if possible).

Comment: Sorry about the incorrect duplicate.  The c_main parameters are a red herring and could be removed from the question. I skipped them in my answer below.

Comment: No worries! I'm sorry for causing trouble. I didn't find how to reply to your private comment, and I was unsure about you getting notified of the comments/edits in a closed question (marked as dup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to access global variables from `ctypes` is to use `in_dll`, but there doesn't seem to be an exposed way to change a function pointer.  I was only able to read it and call it, so I don't think it is possible without a helper function.

The example below alters an `int` global variable, but `CFUNCTYPE` instances don't have a `value` member to alter it.  I added a C helper to set the global to work around the issue and a default value of the callback to verify it was accessed correctly before changing it.

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define API __declspec(dllexport)

typedef void (*CB)();

void dllplot() {
    printf("default\n");
}

API CB plot = dllplot;
API int x = 5;

API int c_main() {
  printf("x=%d (from C)\n",x);
  plot();
  return 0;
}

API void set_cb(CB cb) {
    plot = cb;
}
```

test.py:

```
from ctypes import *

PLOT = CFUNCTYPE(None)

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.c_main.argtypes = ()
dll.c_main.restype = c_int
dll.set_cb.argtypes = PLOT,
dll.set_cb.restype = None

@PLOT
def plotxy():
    print("plotxy")

x = c_int.in_dll(dll,'x')
plot = PLOT.in_dll(dll,'plot')
print(f'x={x.value} (from Python)')
x.value = 7
print('calling plot from Python directly:')
plot()
print('calling c_main():')
dll.c_main()
dll.set_cb(plotxy)
print('calling plot from Python after setting callback:')
plot()
print('calling plot from C after setting callback:')
dll.c_main()
```

Output:

```
x=5 (from Python)
calling plot from Python directly:
default
calling c_main():
x=7 (from C)
default
calling plot from Python after setting callback:
plotxy
calling plot from C after setting callback:
x=7 (from C)
plotxy
```

Note that global pointers use `.contents` to access their value, so I experimented with using a `POINTER(CFUNCTYPE(None))` and using `plot.contents = plotxy` but that doesn't assign the global variable correctly and C crashed.

I even tried adding an actual global pointer to function pointer:

```
API CB plot = dllplot;
API CB* pplot = &plot;
```

and then using:

```
PLOT = CFUNCTYPE(None)
PPLOT = POINTER(PLOT)
plot = PPLOT.in_dll(dll,'pplot')
plot.contents = plotxy
```

That let me assign the function via `.contents`, but `c_main` still called the default plot value.  So the functionality of using `CFUNCTYPE` as anything but a function parameter doesn't appear to be implemented.

Comment: thanks for your insightful answer. It is unfortunate that you confirmed my guess, but I learned about `in_dll` and `__declspec(dllexport)`.