# How do I directly update a C global function pointer variable with Python ctypes?

Tags: python, c, global-variables, function-pointers, ctypes

Consider this `test.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

const char *x = "one";

void set_x(const char *new_x) {
    x = new_x;
}

void print_x(void) {
    printf("x is %s\n", x);
}

void first_f(void) {
    puts("In first function");
}

void (*f)(void) = first_f;

void set_f(void (*new_f)(void)) {
    f = new_f;
}

void do_f(void) {
    f();
}
```

And this `test.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ctypes

def second_f():
    print('In second function')

def third_f():
    print('In third function')

test_so = ctypes.CDLL('./test.so')
x_type = ctypes.c_char_p
f_type = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None)

test_so.set_x.restype = None
test_so.set_x.argtypes = (x_type,)
test_so.print_x.restype = None
test_so.print_x.argtypes = ()

test_so.set_f.restype = None
test_so.set_f.argtypes = (f_type,)
test_so.do_f.restype = None
test_so.do_f.argtypes = ()

test_so.print_x()
x = x_type.in_dll(test_so, 'x')
x.value = b'two'
test_so.print_x()
new_x = x_type(b'three')
test_so.set_x(new_x)
test_so.print_x()

test_so.do_f()
f = f_type.in_dll(test_so, 'f')
f.value = second_f
test_so.do_f()
new_f = f_type(third_f)
test_so.set_f(new_f)
test_so.do_f()
```

When I run `gcc -g -fPIC -shared test.c -o test.so && ./test.py`, I get this output:

```
x is one
x is two
x is three
In first function
In first function
In third function
```

I wanted/expected to get `In second function` instead of the second occurrence of `In first function`.  Why didn't using `in_dll` to set the global variable `f` directly work, when I did everything the same way I did for `x`? Obviously, Python knows how to convert its own functions to C function pointers, since it works fine when I call the setter with `third_f`. But how do I make it work without a setter, like `x` works?

Comment: `CFUNCTYPE` creates function types, not function pointer types. What happens if you create a function pointer type and access `f` through the correct type?

Comment: (Also, you need to keep a reference to the objects created through `f_type`, because ctypes can't do that for you. You're invoking undefined behavior by trying to use callbacks after their lifetimes end.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica You mean if instead of `f_type = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None)`, I do `f_type = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None))`? Then the next-to-last line is unchanged, but the last line is replaced with `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 33, in <module>
    test_so.set_f(f_type(third_f))
TypeError: expected CFunctionType instead of function`.

Comment: I updated my code to keep a reference.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica A `POINTER(CFUNCTYPE(None)` doesn't work either.  A `CFUNCTYPE(NONE)` instance "decays" to pointer to function, so it's more like a double pointer to function.  I played around with that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62957666/235698) (this question could be marked a duplicate of that one) and it doesn't work either.  `ctypes` doesn't seem to support a global function pointer directly and a helper function must be used.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the object returned by fetching `x`, the following doesn't support a `.value` attribute, so has no effect:

```
f = f_type.in_dll(test_so, 'f')
f.value = second_f
```

Setting a function global doesn't seem to be supported by `ctypes`.