# Replace an existing function pointer in a shared library with a python callback without a helper C function

Tags: python, c, callback, function-pointers, ctypes

I am trying to **replace** an **existing function pointer** in a shared library with a **callback defined in Python**, through ctypes and **without using a helper C function** that takes the callback as an argument.

The source of the shared library in C:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void (*plot)();

int c_main(int argc, void** argv) {
  printf("plot is %p\n", (void*)plot);
  assert(plot != NULL);
  plot();
  return 0;
}
```

The source of the Python script:

```
from sys import platform
from pathlib import Path
import ctypes
import _ctypes


FUNCTYPE = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE if platform == 'win32' else ctypes.CFUNCTYPE


def dlclose(obj):
    if platform == "win32":
        _ctypes.FreeLibrary(obj._handle)
    else:
        _ctypes.dlclose(obj._handle)


def enc_args(args):
    C_ARGS = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char) * len(args))()
    for idx, arg in enumerate(args):
        C_ARGS[idx] = ctypes.create_string_buffer(arg.encode("utf-8"))
    return C_ARGS


@FUNCTYPE(None)
def plotxy():
    print("plotxy")


C_ARGS = enc_args([str(Path(__file__))])
CAUXDLL = ctypes.CDLL("./test.so")

print(plotxy)

print(CAUXDLL.plot)

CAUXDLL.plot = plotxy

print(CAUXDLL.plot)

print(CAUXDLL.c_main(len(C_ARGS), C_ARGS))
```

The script to test it:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o test.so test.c
python3 test.py
```

The output I get:

```
# ./test.sh
<CFunctionType object at 0x7fb1f0abb1c0>
<_FuncPtr object at 0x7fb1f0abb640>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7fb1f0abb1c0>
plot is (nil)
python3: test.c:8: c_main: Assertion `plot != NULL' failed.
./test.sh: line 3: 21171 Aborted                 python3 test.py
```

So, it seems that the function defined in Python (plotxy) is of type `CFunctionType`, while the function pointer defined in C is of type `_FuncPtr`. Although the replacement in `CAUXDLL` is applied, it seems to have no effect when the main function is called.

Apart from reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes, I found other questions (e.g. [How to use typedef in ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56706290/how-to-use-typedef-in-ctypes) or [python cytpes creating callback function - Segmentation fault (core dumped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702848/python-cytpes-creating-callback-function-segmentation-fault-core-dumped)), but I cannot find how to convert `CFunctionType` (plotxy) to `_FuncPtr`.

I believe this might not be an issue with the regular usage of ctypes. That's something I have successfully achieved and which is sufficiently explained in the docs. This question goes beyond. I don't want to execute the C function. I want Python to replace an existing function pointer with a callback written in Python. Note that it is possible to do it by using a helper C function (see https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl-cosim/blob/master/vhpidirect/shared/pycb/caux.c#L32-L40). Hence this question is about how to achieve it without that helper function (if possible).

Comment: You never set *plot*, so it's left with the default value that it was initialized to (*NULL*), but it smells like *Undefined Behavior*. Usually callbacks are passed through arguments.

Comment: @CristiFati, defining plot is what I am trying to achieve with `CAUXDLL.plot = plotxy`. The MWE above is a subset of an example where plot has a default non-null value in C: `void (*plot)() = &defaultPlotFcn;`. In that case, no assertion error is produced, which makes the problem more difficult to spot. Hence, it is undefined by default on purpose.
Do you mean that it's "undefined behaviour" to use `plot` uninitialized? Or that it is "undefined behaviour" whether it is possible to override `plot` from Python?
Also note that `CAUXDLL` exists and it is of type `FuncPtr` (so it's being found).